# Solving $x^2-7[x]+5=0.$ to find values of $x$.

Tags: functions

Solve $x^2 - 7[x] + 5 = 0$

We get to know that $x^2$ must be an integer.

But how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: find the intersection of $y=x^2+5$ and $y=7[x]$.

Comment: That $x^2$ is an integer follows of course from $x^2=7[x]-5$

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but the same equation was discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375190/sum-of-squares-of-the-roots-of-equation

Comment: Someone's edited the main heading wrongly. That is not the goal of the question. As OP says, "We get to know that $x^2$ must be an integer." That means it's been inferred from the given info. We don't have to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

As $x-1 \leq [x] \leq x$ you have

$$x^2 -7x+5 \leq 0$$
$$x^2-7x+12 \geq 0$$

Combine those (first is actually enough, but second reduces the number of cases) with $x^2$ integer and you are done.

The first inequality yields

$$\frac{7-\sqrt{29}}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{7+\sqrt{29}}{2}$$
while the second yields $x \leq 3$ or $x \geq 4$.

Thus the solution to the two inequalities is

$$[\frac{7-\sqrt{29}}{2}, 3] \cup [4,\frac{7+\sqrt{29}}{2}] \,.$$

This implies $x^2$ is integer and

$$x^2 \in[(\frac{7-\sqrt{29}}{2})^2, 9] \cup [16,(\frac{7+\sqrt{29}}{2})^2]\,.$$

As

$$(\frac{7-\sqrt{29}}{2})^2 \sim 0.6 \,;\, (\frac{7+\sqrt{29}}{2})^2 \sim 38.3 \,,$$

you get

$$x^2 \in \left( [1, 9] \cup [16,38] \right) \cap \mathbb Z \,.$$

Also, note that $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ which reduces the potential solutions to

$$x^2 \in \{ 2, 9, 16, 23, 30, 37 \}$$

and you need to check which of those work.

Comment: what is the final answer?

Comment: Do you not know how to solve a quadratic inequality, maths lover?

Comment: i noe but i want to know the answer mine are root(2,23,30,37) but there must be 6 solutions what are the other 2?

Comment: Actually, $[x - 1]<x$, so we need $x<3$ or $x>4$, strictly.

Comment: What makes you think there are six solutions?

Comment: Oops.  Meant $x-1<[x]$.

Comment: Note that $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ lies sharply in $[0,1)$ rather than $[0,1]$.  Carefully using this eliminates the two false solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $[x]<0$ if $x<0$, hence $x<0$ implies
$x^2-7[x]+5>5$.
At the other end, $x\ge 7$ together with $[x]\le x$ implies $x^2-7[x]+5\ge x^2-7x+5=(x-7)x+5\ge 5$.
We conclude $[x]\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and hence $x^2=7[x]-5\in\{-5,2,9,16,23,30,37\}$, i.e. (as $x\ge 0$) we have $x\in\{\sqrt 2, 3, 4, \sqrt{23},\sqrt{30}\sqrt{37}\}$. Checking against the original equation leaves only 
$$ x\in\{\sqrt 2,\sqrt{23},\sqrt{30},\sqrt{37}\}$$
as valid solutions.